# Bind Datatable to a Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, repeater, datarow

I'm trying to bind a datatable to a repeater on aspx. I'm getting the below mentioned error at "DataBind" method. I'm tired of trying to fix this since yesterday. This is the code I have:

ASPX:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="HistoryList" runat="server">
  <HeaderTemplate>
    <table class="dataTable" style="width:100%;border-collapse: collapse;padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;">
      <tr>
        <td class="dataHeaderCell">#</td>
        <td class="dataHeaderCell">Date</td>
        <td class="dataHeaderCell">Dealer</td>
        <td class="dataHeaderCell">Security</td>
        <td class="dataHeaderCell">Bid</td>
     </tr>
  </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <td class="dataCell right" title='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "HistoryId") %>'><%# Container.ItemIndex + 1 %></td>
        <td class="dataCell"><%# (null != DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "EffectiveDate")) ? ((DateTime)DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "EffectiveDate")).ToString("d") : "..."%></td>
        <td class="dataCell"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "OrganizationName") %></td>
        <td class="dataCell nowrap"><a target="_blank" title="Click Here to View Name..." href='NameView.aspx?page=27&nid=<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "SecurityId") %>'><%# (60587 == (int)DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "NameId")) ? DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Expr1").ToString() + " (Unknown)" : DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Name").ToString() %></a></td>
        <td class="dataCell nowrap"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Bid") %></td>
    </ItemTemplate>
  </table>
</asp:Repeater>
```

CS.aspx:

```
  string dbConnect = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["dbConnect"].ToString();
  SqlConnection thisConnection = new SqlConnection(@dbConnect);
  thisConnection.Open();

  SqlCommand customCommand = new SqlCommand(queryString.ToString());
  customCommand.Connection = thisConnection;
  customCommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(customCommand4);
  adapter.Fill(dt);

  DataTable newsDataTable = new DataTable();

  foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
  {
    //check for something 
    if (true)
    {
        newsDataTable.ImportRow(dr);
    }
  }

  if (0 < newsDataTable.Rows.Count)
  {
    HistoryList.DataSource = newsDataTable;
    HistoryList.DataBind();
    HistoryList.Visible = true;
    HistoryTitle.Text = string.Format(HistoryTitle.Text, HistoryColor.Count);
  }
```

The error I'm struggling with is:

```
    DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'HistoryId'. --->    at System.Web.UI.DataBinder.GetPropertyValue(Object container, String propName)
       at System.Web.UI.DataBinder.Eval(Object container, String[] expressionParts)
       at System.Web.UI.DataBinder.Eval(Object container, String expression)
       at ASP.comps_aspx.__DataBind__control60(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\sk\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\DynamicWeb\Comps.aspx:line 562
       at System.Web.UI.Control.OnDataBinding(EventArgs e)
       at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind(Boolean raiseOnDataBinding)
       at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind()
       at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBindChildren()
       at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind(Boolean raiseOnDataBinding)
       at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind()
       at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater.CreateItem(Int32 itemIndex, ListItemType itemType, Boolean dataBind, Object dataItem)
       at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater.AddDataItemsIntoItemsArray(IEnumerable dataSource, Boolean useDataSource)
       at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater.PostGetDataAction(IEnumerable dataSource)
       at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater.CreateControlHierarchy(Boolean useDataSource)
       at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater.OnDataBinding(EventArgs e)
       at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater.DataBind()
       at ClarityDynamicWeb.Comps.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\sk\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\DynamicWeb\Comps.aspx.cs:line 593
```

Can anyone please point out what I'm missing or doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: check this spelling HistoryId or check the query

Comment: like rashfmnb said, check in your query that HistoryId is exists in your select columns.

Comment: `HistoryId` column is in query and is spelled correctly.

Comment: what is inside queryString?

Comment: `SELECT TOP(1000) HistoryId, NameId, EffectiveDate, Bid, SecurityId, OrganizationName from TableName where Some condition`

Comment: did you try assigning datatable directly to repeater data source - HistoryList.DataSource = dt;

Comment: I don't want all the data in `dt`, I only need few rows in it. So I didn't do what you mentioned.

Comment: hope you used debugger to see the content / fields inside newsDataTable

Comment: Yes, `newsDataTable.Rows.Count` shows there are 6 rows, but couldn't display it!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110187/discussion-between-techspider-and-csk).

Comment: debug it step by step to see if you actually get the data as you expect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modified `DataTable newsDataTable = new DataTable();`
to `DataTable newsDataTable = dt.Clone();` and instead of `newsDataTable.ImportRow(dr);` used `newsDataTable.Rows.Add(dr.ItemArray);`